# Make the 'all' filter default instead of 'mine' in a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, actions

I reckon this one is quick and easy... I think I'm just missing something very obvious.  My inquiry is nearly identical to [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23800440/removed-mine-filter-and-want-to-make-all-be-default-on-post-page).

For non-admin users, the default filter for posts is 'mine' (the full filter list being: mine, all, published, drafts, pending, trash). So, when they click 'posts' for example, they are given a list of their own articles by default. I want it so the 'all' filter is the default.

Using the previously mentioned post, I have got this to work for posts flawlessly with this code:

```
add_action( 'load-edit.php', function() 
{
global $typenow;

// Not our post type, bail out
if( 'post' !== $typenow )
    return;

// Administrator users don't need this, bail out
if( current_user_can('add_users') )
    return;

// Only the Mine tab fills this conditions, redirect
if( !isset( $_GET['post_status'] ) && !isset( $_GET['all_posts'] ) )
{
    wp_redirect( admin_url('edit.php?all_posts=1') );
    exit();
}   
});
```

Great! Wonderful!

But I also want to apply this to a custom post type I've created. The post type slug is 'community', the plural label is 'Blog Posts' and the singular is 'Blog Post'.  This is the code I produced based on the above code:

```
add_action( 'load-edit-community.php', function() 
{
global $typenow;

// Not our post type, bail out
if( 'community' !== $typenow )
    return;

// Administrator users don't need this, bail out
if( current_user_can('add_users') )
    return;

// Only the Mine tab fills this conditions, redirect
if( !isset( $_GET['blog_post_status'] ) && !isset( $_GET['all_blog_posts'] ) )
{
    wp_redirect( admin_url('edit.php?post_type=community&all_posts=1') );
    exit();
}   
});
```

I tried a few combinations but still can't seem to get it work (luckily they didn't bring my site down).  I tried to place this above and below the working code for the regular 'post' type, but it didn't matter.

Would appreciate any help with this! Thanks.

**EDIT:** got it working now. seems i was trying to jump on a false hook.  here is the working code:

```
add_action( 'load-edit.php', function() 
{
global $typenow;

// Not our post type, bail out
if( 'community' !== $typenow )
    return;

// Administrator users don't need this, bail out
if( current_user_can('add_users') )
    return;

// Only the Mine tab fills this conditions, redirect
if( !isset( $_GET['post_status'] ) && !isset( $_GET['all_posts'] ) )
{
    wp_redirect( admin_url('edit.php?post_type=community&all_posts=1') );
    exit();
}   
});
```

thanks @birgire!

Comment: I'm not sure `load-edit-community.php` is a hook that exists.

Comment: ahhh!!! i see!! i got it working now because of this.  thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

answer ^^

```
add_action( 'load-edit.php', function() 
{
global $typenow;

// Not our post type, bail out
if( 'community' !== $typenow )
    return;

// Administrator users don't need this, bail out
if( current_user_can('add_users') )
    return;

// Only the Mine tab fills this conditions, redirect
if( !isset( $_GET['post_status'] ) && !isset( $_GET['all_posts'] ) )
{
    wp_redirect( admin_url('edit.php?post_type=community&all_posts=1') );
    exit();
}   
});
```

Comment: Still the correct approach and works in 2021

Answer (score -1):

I think that a better solution would be to use the pre_get_posts hook and unset the author parameter.

It could be something like this:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts',function($query){
    //Some check. E.g checking a specific user role
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'author' ) ) {
         return;
    }

    unset( $query->query['author'] );
    unset( $query->query_vars['author'] );
});
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.