# Why "Mine" is the default view when adding 'capability_type' in register_post_type

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles, capabilities, permissions, views

I'm tweaking default's wordpress permissions by adding my own via the `capability_type` and `map_meta_cap` in `register_post_type()`, but I noticed that as soon I add the `capability_type` argument, the default view when I click on `View Posts` is set to `mine`.

```
register_post_type(
   'devis',
   array(
    [...]
      'capability_type' => array('devis', 'deviss'), // Without this line, All posts is the default view
    [...]
   )
);
```

I found how to solved this "problem" with this post:
[Make the 'all' filter default instead of 'mine' in a custom post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/188084/make-the-all-filter-default-instead-of-mine-in-a-custom-post-type)

By unset the author in the `WP_Query`, but is that the proper way of doing it ? Will there be any side effect by removing this ?

*When I comment the capability_type, the author isn't set in the query vars so that's why all posts is the default view*

EDIT

I already mapped the new capabilities to the roles:

```
function add_devis_role_caps() {
   $roles = array('administrator', 'subscriber');

   foreach ($roles as $role) {
      $role = get_role($role);
      if (empty($role)) continue;
      $role->add_cap('read');
      $role->add_cap('edit_deviss');
      $role->add_cap('delete_deviss');
      $role->add_cap('publish_deviss');
      $role->add_cap('edit_others_posts');
   }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'add_devis_role_caps');
```

And I added a custom filtering to display others posts depending on a `meta_value` for the post_type:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function(WP_Query $query) {
    if ($query->get('post_type') !== 'devis') return;
    if (current_user_can('administrator')) return;
    if ($query->is_main_query() && is_admin()) {
        $query->set('meta_key', 'partenaire');
        $query->set('meta_value', get_current_user_id());
        // unset( $query->query['author'] );
        // unset( $query->query_vars['author'] );
    }
});
```

You can see that's where I unset the author in the WP_Query

And the permissions handling (not all permissions are handled for now, not sure if it will be necessary for my case)

```
add_filter('map_meta_cap', function($caps, $cap, $user_id, $args) {
    if ($cap === 'edit_devis' && !empty($args)) {
        $caps = array();
        $devis = get_post($args[0]);
        $post_type = get_post_type_object($devis->post_type);
        if (current_user_can('administrator')) {
            $caps[] = $post_type->cap->edit_posts;
            return $caps;
        }
        if (empty($devis)) {
            $caps[] = 'do_not_allow';
            return $caps;
        }
        if ((int) get_field('partenaire', $args[0]) === (int) $user_id) {
            $caps[] = $post_type->cap->edit_posts;
        } else {
            $caps[] = 'do_not_allow';
        }
    }

    if ($cap === 'delete_devis' && !empty($args)) {
        $caps = array();
        $devis = get_post($args[0]);
        $post_type = get_post_type_object($devis->post_type);
        if (current_user_can('administrator')) {
            $caps[] = $post_type->cap->delete_posts;
            return $caps;
        }
    }
    return $caps;
}, 10, 4);
```

Comment: If you're using a custom capability type you will need to actually assign those capabilities to a role or user. It will not happen automatically. In your example, there will be capabilities like `edit_deviss`, but no roles will have that capability.

Comment: Yes, I should've mention it, I already mapped capabilities to the correct roles, and I added which user can edit posts etc ...
I will edit my post :D

Comment: You’ve added `edit_others_posts` instead of `edit_others_deviss`.

Comment: Ohh, makes so much sense now, all of this for a copy paste mistake, well thanks you then 